# How to get an HTML element to stick to right side of screen

Tags: css

I have an AngularJS app that dynamically displays a person's notes. I want the dropdown select element to stick to the right side (so they line up correctly), but I can't quite get it to not be affected by the element (where it says "phone/text") before it. What is the correct way to do this?

[image]

HTML

```
<!--  -->
<!-- Note holder -->
<!--  -->
<div class="note-wrapper" ng-repeat="note in vm.myData[0].contactHistoryContainer track by $index">

 <div class="contact-history-date-device-wrapper">
   <p class="contact-history-date-device-text">
    {{note.contactHistoryNoteDate}} | {{note.contactHistoryNoteDevice}}
   </p>
 </div>

 <select class="browser-default contact-history-button">
   <option value="1" ng-model="vm.myData[0].contactHistoryIncomingOutgoing">Incoming</option>
   <option value="2" ng-model="vm.myData[0].contactHistoryIncomingOutgoing">Outgoing</option>
 </select>



 <div class="contact-history-note-text-wrapper">
   <p class="contact-history-note-text">
     {{note.contactHistoryNoteText}}
   </p>
 </div>

 <div class="contact-history-horizontal-line"></div>
```

CSS

```
.contact-history-date-device-text {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 500;
 color: #505C64;
 text-transform: capitalize;
}

.contact-history-date-device-wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contact-history-note-text-wrapper {
  height: 20px;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.contact-history-note-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #626F77;
  height: 16px;
}

.contact-history-horizontal-line {
  height: 1px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  background-color: rgba(80, 92, 100, 0.1);
  margin-top: 40px;
}


.contact-history-button {
  width: 175px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.4);
  display: inline-block !important;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}

.edit-note-wrapper {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `.contact-history-button` to have:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

Instead of left:50%;

And then add `position:relative` to the parent element.

It'll them always stick to the right hand side of the parent no matter what, you can adjust the top/right positions to make it line up with other elements.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did that, and they are on the right, however they seem to be fixed, and do not scroll with the screen, although the DOM does not show them having a 'fixed' property

Comment: I'd need a better sample then to play with. Drop some rendered HTML into a jsfiddle.